# How to pass data between selector tags from one component to other

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-directives

I have 2 components,

Component A:

```
<app-selector [test]="title"></app-selector>
export class AssignerComponent implements OnInit {
    title:any = 'get';
    constructor() {}
 }
```

Component B:

```
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() test:any;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.test)
    }
}
```

But unable to get the value of test in component B from A.It is undefined.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to pass data from component A to component B through the `test` input. However, you are seeing `undefined` for the value of `this.test` because you are trying to log it to the console from the `constructor`, which is before it has been set to the value you passed.

If you move that `console.log(this.test)` statement to the `ngOnInit` method, you will see the desired behavior:

```
  Component B:
  export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() test:any;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.test);
    }
  }
```

Here's more information on lifecycle hooks and the way Angular components are created: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks